# Equality assertion failing for macroexpand

Tags: macros, clojure

I have this macro (from the [clojure-koans](https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans)) that should allow the use of infix operators:

```
(defmacro infix-better [form]
  `(~(second form)
    (first form)
    (last form) ))
```

It does what it is supposed to, but doesn't exactly expand to the same expression. For example:

```
user=> (= '(* 10 2) (macroexpand '(infix-better (10 * 2))))
false
user=> '(* 10 2)                                           
(* 10 2)
user=> (macroexpand '(infix-better (10 * 2))) 
(* (clojure.core/first user/form) (clojure.core/last user/form))
```

The last output would end up being `(* 10 2)` when the inner expressions are evaluated but the equality test returns false since `(clojure.core/first user/form)`, strictly speaking, isn't `10`.

How can I have the expanded macro equal the equivalent hard-coded Clojure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to unquote the second and third forms, just like you did the first, with `~` - "The last output would end up being (* 10 2) when the inner expressions are evaluated" is not in any way true - the inner expressions have already passed their chance to be evaluated.

```
(defmacro infix-better [form]
  `(~(second form)
    ~(first form)
    ~(last form)))
```

Would fix it and keep your code structured the same, but really destructuring gives you a much nicer result:

```
(defmacro infix-better [[x op y]]
  (list op x y)) ;; or `(~op ~x ~y)
```